# How do I make an executable for multiple commands?

Tags: executable

Ok, so I am a complete beginner to Linux and just recently installed Lubuntu 20.04 on a slower laptop. Now it is quite fast and I wish to make what I believe is an executable. I want to make a desktop icon (or on plank) that executes two commands when I click on it. First I want it to connect to my vpn server using “- connect”, and when it has connected open a website in Firefox. I have searched for answers and tried to understand, but it is complicated for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I would create a shell script (batch file), make it executable (`chmod +x`) then create a desktop icon that executes it. The Lubuntu manual covers the creation of desktop icons https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html .  I don't know if you can then put this on the *Quick Launch* bar, but the manual covers that too (you'd probably need to add it to the menu first, but that's rather technical I suspect for the manual). This is overview only.

Answer (score 1):

As @guiverc indicates, you have to create a "script", it is a simple text file which allows you to execute certain commands

- On the Desktop, right-click then create a "text" file, give it the name you want *(without extension)*.
- once the text editor is open (Leafpad), enter the following lines:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

Here indicates the command line that allows you to launch your VPN client

firefox http://your site url
```

---

- Save the file
- right-click on this file, and change the "permissions" to make it **executable**

Now you have a script that will execute your 2 commands
You can test it by the console terminal  *(to see any errors)*, if it works, by double-clicking on its icon on the desktop it should also work.

then search the net to find out how to change the type of icons, put it in the menus etc etc ...

once your script is created, even if it is not on your desktop, you can create an "application" file, it is a configuration file which indicates where your script is, which icon is used etc..*(again, it's a simple text file)*

example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Name_of_Applicatio_free         <- a free Name, like you want
Exec=/home/you/myscriptname          <- Path and name of the script you have created
Icon=/usr/share/icons/.../icone.jpeg  <- path and name of a icon file
Type=Application
```